# How can i set a height to div according to step by step div

Tags: php, html, css

When i am listing products i want them to have fixed height according to its step by step div's max height. For example below there is a screenshot from amazon that has what i want. All 4 elements' height are same.
[image: divs are have same height]

and i'm using the code below to list products

```php
<div class="shop-product-wrap">
                                        <div class="row row-8">
                                            <?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>
                                                <div class="product-col col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                                                    <!-- Single Product Start -->
                                                    <div class="single-product-wrap mt-10">
                                                        <div class="product-image">
                                                            <a href="<?= $product['url'] ?>"><img class="lazy"
                                                                                                  src="<?= public_url('images/other/thumbnail.jpg') ?>"
                                                                                                  data-src="<?= image_url($product['image_small']) ?>"
                                                                                                  alt=""></a>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="product-button">
                                                            <a onclick="wishlist.add(<?= $product['product_id'] ?>)"
                                                               class="add-to-wishlist">
                                                                <i class="icon-heart"></i></a>

                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="product-content">
                                                            <h6 class="product-name"><a
                                                                        href="<?= $product['url'] ?>"><?= $product['product_name'] ?></a>
                                                            </h6>
                                                            <div class="starts-icon-box">
                                                                <i class="stars-icon"></i>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="price-box">
                                                                <div class="single-product-discount-and-price">
                                                                    <?php if ($product['product_discount_price']): ?>
                                                                        <span class="onsale"><?= (100 - (round(($product['product_price'] * 100) / $product['product_discount_price']))) . '%' ?></span>
                                                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                                                    <div class="old-and-new-price">
                                                                        <span class="old-price"><?= $product['product_discount_price'] ?> TL</span>
                                                                        <span class="new-price"><?= number_format($product['product_price'], 2) ?> TL</span>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="product-button-action">
                                                                <a onclick="cart.add(<?= $product['product_id'] ?>,1)"
                                                                   class="add-to-cart">Add to cart</a>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <!-- Single Product End -->
                                                </div>
                                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

and when i listing products they all take the height they can according to their content such as its name and so that they don't have the same height. How can i make them have same height step-by-step.
Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use div tag with **same class name** for every product item and add a parent div like this...

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">Item 1</div>
    <div class="child">Item 2</div>
    <div class="child">Item 3</div>
    <div class="child">Item 4</div>
</div>
```

---

Then use **flex box** for parent and child element...

```
.parent{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: stretch;
  height: 600px; /*or something*/
}
.child{
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

Please visit those links for more information about flex box...

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox_align-content_stretch